# Any idioms opposite to "what's the catch/here's the catch"?

Tags: idioms

I'm just wondering if there is any idioms that has the meaning opposite to "what's the catch", to describe a situation that has at a least one advantage/benefit etc despite all kinds of difficulties.

Can anyone help with this? Thank you!!

Comment: You might consider ***"no strings attached"*** to refer to something that *does not have a catch*, though I'm not certain that's what you're looking for when you say "opposite to 'what's the catch.'"

Comment: That's probably the best answer, @SeldomNeedy - guessing at what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 7):

The common metaphor is *every cloud* [dark, ominous, unpleasant thing] *has a **silver lining*** [redeeming feature; element of good, and hope].

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/silver-lining):

> ## Silver Lining
>
> *noun*
>
> A comforting or **hopeful aspect of an otherwise desperate or unhappy situation** (esp in the phrase every cloud has a silver lining)

Similar but with more emphasis on "hope" and less on a current, concrete benefit of the thing-as-it-is (also from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/light-at-the-end-of-the-tunnel)):

> ## Light at the end of the tunnel
>
> hope for the ending of a difficult or unpleasant situation

Comment: And the ever-popular *remind me why we're doing this again*.

Comment: Be sure to watch the amazing Pixar short, with the Brad Paisley song _Every cloud has a silver lining_.

Comment: @Fattie which one ? [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfyJQEIsMt0) is with clouds, but can't really see the silver lining

Comment: hey @CiprianTomoiaga !  google Brad Paisley, Pixar

Answer (score 2):

"Silver lining" is good. There are a number of other stock phrases that might be applicable.

"[Description of the problem]. **On the bright side,** [description of the advantage/benefit]." Also *"on a positive note"*, *"on the up side"*, etc.

A more recent common form is the meme ["So I got that goin' for me, which is nice"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/so-i-got-that-goin-for-me-which-is-nice), originally from the movie *Caddyshack*.

Comment: The phrase "on the bright side" is spot-on!  It seems a better analog for "the catch" than the "silver lining" I suggested.  I prefer it.  Also I love that meme! If I could give you more than one vote, I would.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **"what's the pay-off?"** from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pay-off) section 1.2 to describe the converse situation, where there is a reward from a difficult or apparently hopeless situation. Some of the examples are:

> Which is a shame, because the final pay-off is worthwhile, and despite
>   all the frustrations I did enjoy it.
>
> But the biggest pay-off of her improved chemistry grade was her mother
>   getting off her back.

And so on.